# Snowflake Serverless Tasks

Tags: task, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, serverless

Does anyone know when Snowflake Serverless Tasks might come out of preview and be generally available?

I've seen a couple of articles about it being in a preview with some Snowflake customers, but can't find anymore info further to that.

Comment: I deleted my answer since it was not useful.

Comment: Quick answer is "in the future!". If you'd like to get into a private preview, talk to your account manager.

Comment: @FelipeHoffa I guess the future is now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of August 2021 this feature is still in [preview](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/release-notes/preview-features.html#features-currently-in-preview).

> *I've seen a couple of articles about it being in a preview with some Snowflake customers, but can't find anymore info further to that.*

The documentation is available at
**[Introduction to Tasks](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tasks-intro.html#introduction-to-tasks)**

> **[Compute Resources](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tasks-intro.html#compute-resources)**
>
> Tasks require compute resources to execute SQL code. Either of the following compute models can be chosen for individual tasks:
>
> - **Snowflake-managed**
>
> Also referred to as the serverless compute model, this option relies on compute resources managed by Snowflake. These resources are automatically resized and scaled up or down by Snowflake as required for each workload.

> **[Billing for Task Runs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tasks-intro.html#billing-for-task-runs)**
>
> **Snowflake-managed resources (i.e. serverless compute model)**
>
> Snowflake bills your account based on the actual compute resource usage; in contrast with customer-managed virtual warehouses, which consume credits when active, and may sit idle or be overutilized. Charges are calculated based on total usage of the resources (including cloud service usage) measured in compute-hours credit usage.

---

The **[CREATE TASK](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-task.html)** was also updated:

> ```
> CREATE [ OR REPLACE ] TASK [ IF NOT EXISTS ] <name>
> [ WAREHOUSE = <string> ]
> ```

Warehouse name becomes an [optional parameter](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-task.html#optional-parameters).